# How do you make an item complete one transition before starting another?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to make my program have an item first transition up, and *then* right in the JavaScript section of code.

```
arrow.style.top = "0px";
arrow.style.left = guess * 9 + "px";
```

I've tried setting a delay but regardless of where I place the line of code, the item stops, and then does both anyway. Is there a way to make it wait for one transition to complete then start the second, or at least make the second transition wait a certain amount of time before beginning?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the element is animating using the CSS3 transition?

Comment: Do you want to simply move the item in two steps or do you want to animate it over time?

Comment: Yes, it is using the CSS3 transition. I want it to glide upward, then glide to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery` call back functions.
pass the second `animate` function as an argument (call back) to first `animate` function . The second function will be called automatically when the first function finishes.
   You may chain a number of animations this way.

see this demo
(click on the red square);

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxzkL6vy/

```js
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({"left":"100px"},300,function(){
         $(this).animate({"top":"100px"},300);
    })
});
```

```css
div{
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```